# Add multidimensional data to each row of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I want to add 2D data to each row of a column. `df['column_name'] = X` where X is a NumPy array is of shape (20000,10,128). I want 20000 rows of (10, 128) data. But executing the above code throws `AssertionError: Shape of new values must be compatible with manager shape` error. Please suggest something.

Comment: `X` needs to be a list of 20000 arrays (each (10,128)).  Each row of `df['column_name']` will be a separate (10,128) shaped array; it will be a object dtype series.  `pandas` does not store 3d arrays.

Comment: Worked @hpaulj.Thanks